# Why can't I have std::optional<T> where T is abstract?

Tags: c++, templates, virtual, abstract, option-type

This does not work:

```
struct Type {
    virtual bool func(const std::string& val) const noexcept = 0;
}

// in main
optional<Type> = some_function_returning_optional_type();
```

and fails with a error message:

```
error: cannot declare field 'std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::_Optional_base<Type, false>::<anonymous union>::_M_payload' to be of abstract type 'Type'
```

Changing the `Type` to have a non-pure function works, but is not appropriate in this case, because there cannot be an instance of `Type` in my code, only classes which inherit from it should be able to exist.

Comment: How do you even instantiate the abstract type to be put in an optional? If you are actually instantiating a concrete type, but use a pointer to the abstract type, then you could put a pointer (or a smart pointer) into your optional. Note however that you only need an optional if `nullptr` is not sufficient and you need to handle a special case when even a `nullptr` could not be created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::optional<T>` stores its value in-place - it therefore needs to know the size of `T` to work correctly, and `T` must be a concrete type that can be instantiated. You can think of `std::optional<T>` as:

```
template <typename T>
struct optional
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> _data;
    bool _set;
};
```

An abstract type represents an interface - polymorphism and some sort of indirection are required to work with abstract types. `std::optional` doesn't have any indirection by design.

Comment: So, when I understand this correctly, hiding the `Type` behind a (smart) pointer would do the trick?

Comment: @musicmatze: you can have a `std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Type>>`. But why not use `std::unique_ptr<Type>` then?

Comment: @musicmatze polymorphism always requires indirection.

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks. Having a `optional<>` around it would be more fitting in a semantical way, and it is not runtime critical, so I'll gladly pay this price! Thanks!

Comment: @musicmatze A pointer is implicitly nullable, and that represents an invalid return value

Comment: @musicmatze suppose you have use `std::optional<std::unique_ptr<Type>>`. Now what happens if someone puts a `nullptr` in there? I could see a reason to use `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<Type>>`, but that isn't owning

Comment: The size of an abstract class is known, no? It's just useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposal of optional will of course work but it would offend me to have to write

```
x.value()->do_something();
```

and I'd be concerned that users might do something daft:

```
x.value().reset();  // now what?
```

We can achieve polymorphism with a non-polymorphic interface by using a wrapper.

Here's one way:

```
#include <optional>
#include <iostream>

// the Foo interface/base class
struct Foo
{
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
    virtual Foo* clone() const { return new Foo(*this); }

    virtual void do_something() {
        std::cout << "something Fooey\n";
    }
};

// a service for managing Foo and classes derived from Foo
struct FooService
{
    template<class Arg>
    Foo* clone(Arg&& arg)
    {
        using d_type = std::decay_t<Arg>; 
        return new d_type(std::forward<Arg>(arg));
    }

    template<class Arg>
    Foo* clone(Foo* arg)
    {
        return arg->clone();
    }

    Foo* release(Foo*& other) noexcept
    {
        auto tmp = other;
        other = nullptr;
        return tmp;
    }
};

// implement the Foo interface in terms of a pimpl
template<class Holder>
struct BasicFoo
{

    decltype(auto) do_something() {
        return get().do_something();
    }



private:
    Foo& get() noexcept { return static_cast<Holder*>(this)->get_impl(); }
    Foo const& get() const noexcept { return static_cast<Holder const*>(this)->get_impl(); }
};


// a type for holding anything derived from a Foo
// can be initialised by anything Foo-like and handles copy/move correctly
struct FooHolder : BasicFoo<FooHolder>
{
    template
    <
        class Arg,
        std::enable_if_t
        <
            std::is_base_of_v<Foo, std::decay_t<Arg>>
        >* = nullptr
    >
    FooHolder(Arg&& arg)
    : service_()
    , ptr_(service_.clone(std::forward<Arg>(arg)))
    {}

    FooHolder(FooHolder const& other)
    : service_()
    , ptr_(other.ptr_->clone())
    {
    }

    FooHolder(FooHolder && other) noexcept
    : service_()
    , ptr_(service_.release(other.ptr_))
    {
    }

    FooHolder& operator=(FooHolder const& other)
    {
        auto tmp = other;
        std::swap(ptr_, tmp.ptr_);
        return *this;
    }

    FooHolder& operator=(FooHolder && other) noexcept
    {
        auto tmp = std::move(other);
        std::swap(ptr_, tmp.ptr_);
        return *this;
    }

    ~FooHolder()
    {
        delete ptr_;
    }

    Foo& get_impl() noexcept { return *ptr_; }
    Foo const& get_impl() const noexcept { return *ptr_; }

    FooService service_;
    Foo* ptr_;
};

// now we can supply as many overrides of Foo as we like    
struct Bar : Foo
{
    virtual Foo* clone() const { return FooService().clone(*this); }

    virtual void do_something() {
        std::cout << "something Barey\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::optional<FooHolder> opt;

    // note that we're initialising cleanly    
    opt = Bar {};

    // and we don't expose the pointer so the user can't
    // destroy the pimpl accidentally
    opt.value().do_something();
}
```